# PyMongo: How To Use Aggregate And Store The Results To Another Collection?

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

Assume a collection with documents which look like this:

```
{
    "username" : "Aventinus"
    "text": "I love StackOverflow!",
    "tags": [
      "programming",
      "mongodb"
    ]
}
```

Using text index and the following command in MongoDB I can find all documents whose text contains the word `StackOverflow` and store them in another collection:

```
db.C_a.aggregate([
  {$match: {$text: {$search:"StackOverflow"}}},
  {$out:"C_b"}
]);
```

However, I would like to run the above snippet for a list of keywords (more than 200) so I need to automate this process by writing a Python script.

**Question**: What is the equivalent of the above snippet in PyMongo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following is the workable code tested on pymongo version 3.6.1 and python 3.6.4

```
    import pymongo
    from pymongo import MongoClient
    client = MongoClient('127.0.0.1')  # mongodb running locally
    dbRead = client['test']            # using the test database in mongo
    # create the pipeline required 
    pipeline = [{"$match": {"$text": {"$search":"StackOverflow"}}},{"$out":"C_b"}]  # all attribute and operator need to quoted in pymongo
    dbRead.C_a.aggregate(pipeline)  #execution 
    print (dbRead.C_b.count()) ## verify count of the new collection
```